# Typescript errors when not all properties of HTMLScriptElement are provided

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm appending a script to the page in a typescript file.

```
function getScript() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
    script.async = true;
    script.src = './scripts/my-script.js';
  });
}
```

Typescript gives me the following error, which I've had before on `img` tags, except the error indicated I was missing many, many more properties.

> `Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLScriptElement': async, charset, crossOrigin, defer, and 8 more.ts(2740)`

I don't want to use/specify all of the properties available on the script element's interface: should I use something more generic (what?), or just omit the interface entirely? Or is there a way to use an interface so I get the intellisense helpers for autocomplete, warning me if a prop doesn't exist on the interface, but being silent when I don't use them all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `SCRIPT` to `script` and TypeScript will realize that `createElement()` returns an `HTMLScriptElement`.

Comment: Interested parties can consult the TS standard library's type declaration for [`Document.createElement()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4440) which mentions the [`HTMLElementTagNameMap` interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L17922) containing the relevant [`script`/`HTMLScriptElement` key-value pair](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18013)

Comment: Typescript can also infer the type automatically, so it's not required to set `const foo: HTMLScriptElement = ...`